# Should I delete .pyc files if I copy project to new comptuer

Tags: python

Should I delete the .pyc files if I copy a project from one computer to another, lets say a linux machine to a windows machine?  Or will it automatically correct itself.

Comment: in terms of git, you should ignore *.pyc for house keeping

Answer (score 1):

They'll be fine.  They are not dependent on the OS or the hardware; they are only dependent on the Python version.  Python automatically creates, and updates, them when needed.

Comment: Lets say I have a file that works with both python3 and python2 and I copy it from a machine with python2 to a machine with python3, what should I do in this case?

Comment: @abden003 python3 sticks it's .pyc files in a `__pycache__` directory, so, again, nothing special needs to be done.

Comment: NightShadeQueen's comment is correct since Python 3.2;  see [PEP 3147](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/)